# Generic way to stay within Google BigQuery SQL Query quota

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Running this SQL query against a public dataset:

```
SELECT
  package,
  COUNT(*) count
FROM (
  SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, '(.*)') package,
    id
  FROM (
    SELECT
      SPLIT(content, '\n') line,
      id
    FROM
      [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.contents]
    WHERE
      sample_path LIKE '%.bashrc' OR sample_path LIKE '%.bash_profile')
  GROUP BY
    package,
    id )
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  count DESC
LIMIT
  400;
```

spawns this error message:

> Error: Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free query
> bytes scanned. For more information, see
> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

`bigquery-public-data:github_repos.contents` goes over my quota.

`bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_contents` is too small.

Are there ways to specify how much quota queries can utilize? If I have a 1TB quota, can I run this query against `github_repos.contents` (which consumes 2.15TB), but stop processing after 1TB?

Comment: This is not possible AFAIK. The table is simply too big for the free tier.

Comment: @GrahamPolley would matching fewer files in the WHERE clause reduce the quota consumed? Would any query against this dataset consume 2.15TB?

Comment: No, because it's neither partitioned or clustered.

Comment: @GrahamPolley Okay, so any possible query against this dataset would be 2.15TB?

Comment: No, depends on the columns you access in your query. But because this table is primarily made up of the "content" column, then any query that accesses that will be big.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Custom Cost Controls](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas#how_to_set_or_modify_custom_quotas). This can be set at project level or user. The user can be a service account. Having different service accounts running each queries you can "specify how much quota a query can utilize".